# Laravel DB class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am just trying to config my Laravel new project, I am working on xampp localhost. When I tried to run my first db insert this error appears "Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\boh\index.php on line 48"

here is my database.php

```
    'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'boh',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

and here the short script:

```
 <?php
    DB::select('INSERT INTO `boh` VALUES name="John"');
    ?>
```

Comment: Where exactly have you put this script? Are you using a controller or have you actually put this into index.php?

Comment: inside of body of my index.php

Comment: You don't touch index.php, you need to setup a controller and then create routes that point to your controller. I would suggest checking out https://laracasts.com/ for some video tutorials on getting started.

Comment: You also can't insert with a select method, I'll add an example in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you to set up a basic controller, route and your SQL query.

app/HTTP/Controllers/TestController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function getInsert()
    {
        DB::table('boh')->insert(
            ['name' => 'john']
        );
    }
}
```

app/HTTP/routes.php

```
<?php

Route::get('insert-test', 'TestController@getInsert');
```

Navigate to yourdomain.com/insert-test